# Proving that two vectors are perpendicular given information of derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Let $f,g:\mathbb {R \to R^{3}}$ two differentiable functions s.t. $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$
> $\quad f(x) = f(x+1), \quad g(x) = g(x+3)$. Show that exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. the vector $u =f(a) - g(b)$ is perpendicular to both $f'(a)$ and $g'(b)$.

Why is it true? Any hint would help. Thank you!

Comment: I think one can assume equivalently that $f(x) = f(x+1),\quad g(x) = g(x+1)$. Nice problem

Comment: @LorenzoPompili that is clearly a weakly stronger assumption, and it's not obvious to me that it is equivalent.

Comment: Hint: I'd expect at least one application of the Intermediate Value Theorem to be necessary.

Comment: @FrankSeidl To see that, I think you can agree with me that $f(x) = f(x+3),\quad g(x) = g(x+3)$ is a weaker assumption and that $f(x) = f(x+1),\quad g(x) = g(x+1)$ is instead stronger. But the problem is equivalent if we assume one of this two assumptions or the other one, just rescaling $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to $f(3x)$ and $g(3x)$ let's say. Thus the intermediate hypothesis of the question should be equivalent to both for the aim of solving the problem

Comment: Just an observation. If you compute $\frac{d}{dx}<f(x)-g(x),f(x)-g(x)>$ and impose that it is equal to $0$ (which must happen for some $x$), you obtain that $2<f'(x),f(x)-g(x)>-2<g'(x),f(x)-g(x)>=0$, that reminds me what we have to find

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I tried to proceed from $2<f′(x),f(x)−g(x)>−2<g′(x),f(x)−g(x)>=0$. I concluded that $g(x) = x+3, f(x)=x+3$ hence both functions are 3-periodic, then there's an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f'(x) = 0 \implies <g′(x),f(x)−g(x)>=0$ and the same about $f$. Am I correct?

Comment: I see some problems. First, if $f'(x)$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it is not always true that $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$ even if it is periodic. Think for instance about $f(x)=(\sin(2\pi x/3),\cos(2\pi x/3),0)$.

Second, even if $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$, then it is not given that it is the same $x$ for which it holds $\frac{d}{dx}<f(x)-g(x),f(x)-g(x)>=0$, so you can't deduce what you have written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it finally. I was finding it more difficult than it was, I thought that you had to choose the same point for both functions (and in that case, the result is not true by the way).

**Geometric argument:**

If you find $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)=g(b)$, then the result is trivially true. So, let's suppose that the two functions have disjoint images. Let's call $A$ the image of $f$ and $B$ the image of $g$.

Since they are both periodic, we can see them as continuous functions from the circle $S^1:=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. But the circle is a compact space, so $A$ and $B$ are compact and disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, as images of compact spaces through continuous maps. They are actually continuous closed curves (even though they could be non-regular).

Then, roughly speaking, by compactness, there are two points $p,q\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $p\in A,\,q\in B$ that minimize the distance between each other, and if we draw the segment that connects these two points, it must be orthogonal to both these curves if both points are regular points of the curves. (If instead they are not, then $f'$ and $g'$ vanish at those points, so there is nothing to prove). Below the rigorous procedure.

---

**Rigorous analytic argument**

Let's consider the function $d:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $d(x,y)=\|f(x)-g(y)\|^2$, where here I am considering the standard Euclidean norm.
Since this function is periodic in both variables (let's assume $f(x) = f(x+1),\quad g(x) = g(x+1)$ for simplicity), it can be seen as a continuous function $\widetilde d\colon S^1\times S^1\to\mathbb{R}$, where the domain $S^1\times S^1$ is compact (it is just a 2-dimensional torus). Thus, $d$ admits maxima and minima.

Let's call $(a,b)$ a minimum point for $d$. We are assuming that $d(a,b)>0$, otherwise the result is clearly obtained. Since $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and $(a,b)$ is a minimum, it must hold
$$\frac{d}{dx}d(x,y)|_{x=a}=0,\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{d}{dy}d(x,y)|_{y=b}=0.$$
If you write explicitly these two derivatives (recall that we can write $d(x,y)=<f(x)-g(y),f(x)-g(y)>$), we obtain exactly $2<f'(a),f(a)-g(b)>=0$ and $2<g'(b),f(a)-g(b)>=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!